# Transition "out" does not work

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a page with full width, when I click the button, the menu open and the content align, like this:

[image]

When I click the menu, the transition works, but when I close not. Why?

```css
// Style When the Menu is Opened
#page-content.page-active{
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#page-content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    transition: width 0.7s;
}
```

Comment: you put the same code ... but i guess you are adding removing classes and you don't set the tansition in all the places

Comment: Hi @kirk. The code you pasted seems fine. The culprit might be somewhere else in your code. Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a CodePen Example for you where you can see the menu transition working. It uses a combination of absolute positioning and width changes.

The menu is offset to the left by its width using

```
position: absolute;
left: -30%;
```

The content has its width at 100%. When the menu toggles, it is animated to `left: 0;` while the content shrinks its width to 70%. You could also use `width: 100%` for the content to make the menu overlap.

https://codepen.io/NikxDa/pen/JMdXWE

Comment: Thank you so much. I defined the position: absolute on the main class and it worked.